# php7 object collection + properties

Tags: php

How can I create an object in php (like c#)

for exemple  user with 3 properties

```
   class Users
{
    private $name;
    private $age;
    private $sex;

    public function __construct($name, $age, $sex) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->sex = $sex;
    }
}
```

how can I add users in the collection
and then loop users collection to  get

```
$user->name
$user->age
$user->sex
```

thank you

Comment: This is a question about [basic documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php). PHP7 also implements *anonymous classes*. A similar approach are *associative arrays*.

Comment: thanks but I couldn't find it, I found only collections with array key=>values.
I want to create a collection of objects with > 2 properties, not only key value

Comment: A value can be everything, also object and array. It's a question of the syntax. `$obj->propname` vs. `$arr['itemname']`. Which PHP version is your question targeting? Assoc. array collection: `for($i = 0; $i<count($arr);$i++) $arr[$i]['itemname']`

Comment: I understand but how can I add many users in my collection

$u = new Users(?)

Answer (score 0):

From you given example, it might be achieved like that:

```
class User
{
  const
    SEX_M = 1,
    SEX_F = 2
  ;

  private
    $name,
    $age,
    $sex
  ;

  public function __construct($name, $age, $sex) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->age  = $age;
    $this->sex  = $sex;
  }

  public function dump()
  {
    echo "name: $this->name, age: $this->age, sex: "
       . ($this->sex === User::SEX_M ? 'm' : 'f') . "<br>\n";
  }
}

$collection = array();
$collection[] = new User('Tom'  , 10, User::SEX_M);
$collection[] = new User('Jerry', 11, User::SEX_F);

foreach ($collection as $user)
  $user->dump();
```

Comment: @ErickBoileau You can even use scalar type hints in younger PHP versions. e.g. `public function __construct(string $name, int $age, int $sex) {`

Comment: Who knows one language, can rapidly get into every language ;)

Comment: yes of course, it's similar , i was just missing $collection = array();
you can do directly a collection of object with C#

Comment: Yes, many languages introduce special features and/or syntax on collections. PHP is a *script* language with its benefits and drawbacks. Type hinting is one of things recently introduced to improve PHP's integrity. I encourage you to make use of it.